# Disable Popup Maker on Certain Conditions

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Is it possible to disable popup maker (wordpress plugin) from opening on certain conditions, like if input is empty or if an item has a class. I'm trying for hours and nothing seems to work.

I'm trying the following:

```
$( '.submit-button' ).click(function(event) {
  if ($('input').val() == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Doesn't work, I can't prevent popup maker from opening at all. Tried using the [API](https://docs.wppopupmaker.com/article/42-popup-maker-jquery-api), still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers don't quite get at the original question so I'll drop this here, better late than never.

Assuming you are using a built in trigger (not manually coded ones) Popup Maker triggers are set up as soon as the page loads, if you want to prevent it for some circumstance you would need to do so via the built in conditional processing that happens just before a shows a popup.

Adding a condition from our [Advanced Targeting Conditions](https://wppopupmaker.com/extensions/advanced-targeting-conditions/) extension or registering your own [custom condition](https://github.com/PopupMaker/Popup-Maker/wiki/Adding-A-Condition) is likely the way to go there.

If your code on the button manually triggers the popup then just modify it as above posted and only call the JS function `PUM.open(123)` (for popup 123) when the input has the correct value.

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit-button', function(e) {
  if ($('input').val() == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    //if above line does not work, please try => return false;
  } else {
    PUM.open(123); // open popup 123
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be: (If I understand what you mean, you forgot to change e to event)

```
$( '.submit-button' ).click(function(event) {
  if ($('input').val() == "") {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

And the `$('input')` selector is too board that may be one of them are not empty. You should change to more clarify selector ex. `$('input#username')`

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to answer if you provide demo link. However, please try these:

**If input is empty:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit-button', function(e) {
  if ($('input').val() == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    //if above line does not work, please try => return false;
  }
});
```

**If item has a class:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit-button', function(e) {
  if ($('#item').hasClass('someclass')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```